# Max Users for WordPress Woocommerce Limited by PHP-FPM Processes Ram Utilization

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce, memory-management

I'm finding that the amount of concurrent users/visitors/connections to my woocommerce website is limited by the amount of RAM available.  Each visitor seems to spawn a PHP-FPM process that is roughly 50-70 MB in size.  My server has 32 GB of ram and I allocate 28 GB to PHP `memory_limit` and 28GB in `innodb_buffer_pool_size` for MariaDB.  When the amount of users reaches 400-500, the server starts to run very slow and will have connection errors. Below are the PHP-FPM settings.

What I'm wondering is if the 50-70 MB per PHP-FPM process is normal.  My WordPress installation does have several plugins.  I could perform a bunch of tests to find out, but was hoping there were some experts out there that really understand what goes on here.  In order to get to 1,500 concurrent users without server lag/hang, I will upgrade my dedicated server with 4X more cores and 4X more ram. However, it would be great to minimize the PHP-FPM process memory if there was a trick or two (like nginx caching).

Thank you for any input you can offer.

```
PHP-FPM settings
pm.max_children=400
pm.max_requests=500
pm=ondemand

PHP: version 7.4.13, run PHP as FPM application served by nginx
Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Wordpress:  5.6
WooCommerce: Version 4.8.0
```

Comment: You have actually multiple questions within one. Try to form your question as one. This forum is for programming questions only, so you better repost in ServerFault.

Comment: I did ask one question with ample background.  It is related to coding.  I knew the first response would be exactly what you wrote.  Here is the question:  "What I'm wondering is if the 50-70 MB per PHP-FPM process is normal."   If someone familiar with these processes wish to expand on what is going on that warrants so much memory, that would be appreciated.